# How to get matrix elements based on names and indexes

Tags: r

As a result of an apply function to matrix (df) columns, I get a list or dataframe "m" with the indexes that match the criteria of my function. How do I get the actual elements based on that?

So for a matrix (df) like this:

```
      col1     col2     col3
[1,]  match1  no        match5
[2,]  no      match3    no
[3,]  no      match4    no
[4,]  match2  no        match6
```

I get this result "m" from the apply function using grep for the word "match":

```
      col1 col2 col3
[1,]    1    2    1
[2,]    4    3    4
```

I ended up getting the right results by changing "value=TRUE" when using grep in the original apply function that returns "m". 
However, if I used df[m] it returned all results based on col1 from df. So I am still wondering how to get the actual elements of "df" based on "m" results. 
Thank you!

Comment: `df1[df2[,1],1]` will give you the values in df1 based on row numbers in df2, for 1st column. You canprobably work out the rest from there

Comment: By the looks of it, you have a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`. Which means you can just do `m <- grep("match", df)` to get the indexes and then `df[m]` to extract the parts.

Comment: Thank you, @dww. I can use a loop to do that using your suggestion.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, it is indeed a matrix.  Your suggestion is much simpler than what I was doing. Thanks!